# Why Does IE 10 Drop the Home Icon When Using Pinned Shortcuts?

Tags: internet-explorer-10

If you drag a URL to the desktop it creates a "Pinned Shortcut". When you launch one of these pinned shortcuts and your default browser is IE 10, the "Home Icon" is no longer available. The Favorites and Tools icons are still available.

How come the "Home Icon" disappears when using a pinned shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you pin a shortcut like that from IE9+, it's "pinning it' instead of creating a more traditional shortcut to a URL.

You'll notice it also gains the site's icon to the left of the navigation buttons, and the navigation buttons will take on the colour hue of the page's icon.

It offers developers features that a normal shortcut couldn't provide.

More info from Microssoft: [Introduction to Pinned Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491738(v=VS.85).aspx)

Blurb:

> A Pinned site is more than just a shortcut, however. With very little
>   effort, developers can access features of the Windows 7 taskbar or
>   Windows 8 Start screen from their websites—features that can greatly
>   improve a user's ability to navigate, control, and interact with the
>   sites they visit.